# Converting a For Loop to a Fold

Tags: scala, fold

I have to analyze an email corpus to see how many of individual sentences are dominated by leet speak (i.e. lol, brb etc.)

For each sentence I am doing the following:

```
   val words = sentence.split(" ")

    for (word <- words) {
      if (validWords.contains(word)) {
        score += 1
      } else if (leetWords.contains(word)) {
        score -= 1
      }
    }
```

Is there a better way to calculate the scores using Fold?

Comment: Please code it exactly that way.   It says exactly what it is doing, simply and cleanly.   Why make it more difficult to read?

Comment: If not limited to fold, using sum would be more concise. `sentence.split(" ").iterator.map(word => if (validWords.contains(word)) 1 else if (leetWords.contains(word)) -1 else 0).sum`

Comment: @thirstycrow that is a really good solution. If you make it an answer, I would like to mark it as accepted. thanks.

Comment: Thanks @SaqibAli, I made it an answer. And I'm glad it's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not limited to fold, using sum would be more concise.

```
sentence.split(" ")
  .iterator
  .map(word =>
    if (validWords.contains(word)) 1
    else if (leetWords.contains(word)) -1
    else 0
  ).sum
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a great deal different, but another option.

```
val words = List("one", "two", "three")
val valid = List("one", "two")
val leet = List("three")

def check(valid: List[String], invalid: List[String])(words:List[String]): Int = words.foldLeft(0){
  case (x, word) if valid.contains(word) => x + 1
  case (x, word) if invalid.contains(word) => x - 1
  case (x, _ ) => x
}

val checkValidOrLeet = check(valid, leet)(_)
val count = checkValidOrLeet(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with fold and partial application. Could still be more elegant, I'll continue to think on it.

```
val sentence = // ...your data....
val validWords = // ... your valid words...
val leetWords = // ... your leet words...

def checkWord(goodList: List[String], badList: List[String])(c: Int, w: String): Int = {
  if (goodList.contains(w)) c + 1
  else if (badList.contains(w)) c - 1
  else c
}

val count = sentence.split(" ").foldLeft(0)(checkWord(validWords, leetWords))
print(count)
```